# how to connect mysql database in grails with intellij IDE

Tags: mysql, grails, intellij-idea

I am new to grails and intellij ide. I have run a grails project in intellij that's ok. But now I need to use mysql database instead of default. I have no idea how to do it. As much as I know i have changed my datasource class like below >>>

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
    properties {
        initialSize = 5
        maxActive = 10
        minIdle = 5
        maxIdle = 5
        maxWait = 100000
        validationQuery = "select 1"
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 60000
    }
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = false
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.provider_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
            loggingSql = true
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/sbicloud_jan_13"
            username = "root"
            password = "admin"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.18.12/sbicloud"
            username = "zia"
            password = "zia123321"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
        }
    }
}
```

when I run the app some errors occur in console and the first is as below >>>

```
    Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Can anyone please help me on this?! It will be so helpful for me.

Comment: Your grails application does not yet have the MySQL drivers available, so you will have to supply those drivers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are more or less 2 approaches:

1. Modify your BuildConfig.groovy so your application will use MySQL. In the BuildConfig there is a block called 'dependencies'

   ```
   dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.20'
    }
   ```

   Uncomment the line:

   ```
   // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.20'
   ```

   And it will download the dependencies.
2. Put MySQL JDBC driver inside the grails-app/lib directory...
   I posted a blog post sometime ago with instruction for this. [Look here](http://www.codeverse.org/2012/09/using-mysql-instead-of-in-memory.html)

Comment: thank you so much buddy. I need your help in future to build my project. I think you won't mind